# Why User site-packages are not visible in virtualenv?

Tags: python, nltk, virtualenv

While installing the [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) module, one of these [prerequisites](https://github.com/DeepRNN/image_captioning#prerequisites), using the commande `pip install --user -U nltk`
in a venv called [dl4cv](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/30/ubuntu-18-04-install-tensorflow-and-keras-for-deep-learning/), I got the error :

`(dl4cv) hdafa@hdafa-HP-ProBook-450-G5:~$ pip install --user -U nltk
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

Any idea to make thse tools visible in the venv, so I can install nltk in dl4cv ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you need the --user argument while a venv is activated.

Simply run `pip install nltk`

Comment: I already tried, and it worked. the nltk module has been successfully installed. Thanks!